# Grep range of numbers in bash

Tags: shell, grep, numbers

How can I grep to see if a string with numbers is within a range of numbers?

I've tried:

```
v1=110
v2=220
echo "app_name_117.sh" | grep -iEo "*.*.($v1|$v2).sh"
```

The range can be between 0 and 999.
No luck so far.

Comment: Is there another solution except grep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regexp should be more complicated: http://regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

This can help you to generate one:  http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator

You can also use awk:

```
$ echo "app_name_117.sh" | awk -F "[_.]" '{if ($3>=117 && $3<=120) print $0}'
```

Awk also supports adding variables in the command line with `-v` switch:

```
$ echo "app_name_117.sh" | awk -F "[_.]" -v v1=110 -v v2=120 '{if ($3>=v1 && $3<=v2) print $0}'
app_name_117.sh

$ echo "app_name_07.sh" | awk -F "[_.]" -v v1=110 -v v2=120 '{if ($3>=v1 && $3<=v2) print $0}'
# no output
```

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use `awk` instead of `grep` to compare a numeric range:

```
echo "app_name_117.sh" | awk -F '[._]+' '$(NF-1) >= 116 && $(NF-1) <= 118' && $NF=="sh"
```

`-F '[._]+'` sets one or more underscore or dot characters as input field separator. We get extension or last field in `$NF`. The number before that is available in `(NF-1)th` field.